# Responsive navigation bar could not be displayed (hamburger menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, hamburger-menu

I am trying to make the so-called "Hambuger menu" which appears very well but when I click it nothing happens.

I have an event listener to listen for any click on that button and then according it would toggle the class to show or hide the ul elements.

I can't find the mistake myself. Is there even a simpler way?

```js
const bar = document.getElementById('bar');
const nav = document.getElementById('navbar');
const close = document.getElementById('close');

if (bar){
    bar.addEventListener("click", () => {       
        nav.classList.toggle("active");
    })
}

if (close) {
    close.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.remove("active")
    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600; 700; 800; 900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif; 
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #222;
}

h2{
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #222;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #222;
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.section-p1 {
    padding: 40px 80px;
}

.section-m1 {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
}

/*Header Start*/

#header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background: #E3E6F3;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
    color: #088178;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
    content: "";
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 20px;
}

#mobile {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Home Page*/

#hero{
    background-image: url("Web images/img/hero4.png");
    height: 99vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top 25% right 0;
    padding: 0 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#hero h4{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#hero h1{
    color: #088178;
}

#hero button {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/button.png");
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #088178;
    border: 0;
    padding: 14px 80px 14px 65px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#hero button:hover {
    color: #46bff7;
}

#Feature {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#Feature .fe-box {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

#Feature .fe-box:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 54px rgba(70, 62, 221, 0.1);
}

#Feature .fe-box img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Feature .fe-box h6 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 8px 6px 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #088178;
    background-color: #fddde4;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(2) h6 {
    background-color: #cdebbc;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(3) h6{
    background-color: #d1e8f2;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(4) h6 {
    background-color: #cdd4f8;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(5) h6 {
    background-color: #f6dbf6;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(6) h6{
    background-color: #fff2e5;
}

#product1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#product1 .pro {
    width: 23%;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin: 15px 0;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;
}

#product1 .pro:hover {
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

#product1 .pro img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro .des {
    text-align: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#product1 .pro .des span {
    color: #606063;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#product1 .pro .des h5 {
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 13.7px;
}

#product1 .pro .des i  {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(241, 186, 7);
}

#product1 .pro .des h4 {
    padding-top: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #088178;
}

#product1 .pro .cart {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #cce7d0;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #088178;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
}

#banner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b2.jpg") ;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
}

#banner h4 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#banner h2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#banner h2 span{
    color: red;
}

#banner button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px 20px ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#banner button:hover {
    background: #088178;
    color: #fff;
}

#sm-banner{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
} 

#sm-banner .banner-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b17.jpg");
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 48%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sm-banner .BB2 {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b10.jpg");
}

#sm-banner .banner-box h4 {
    color: #fff;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 33px;
}
#sm-banner .banner-box span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box .cont {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box button {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 26px ;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box:hover button {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #088178;
    background-color: #088178;
}

#banner-lil {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 80px;
} 

#banner-lil .banner-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b18.jpg");
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-height: 30%;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 30%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#banner-lil .BB3 {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b4.jpg");
}

#banner-lil .BB4  {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b7.jpg");
}

#banner-lil .BB4 h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}

#banner-lil h4 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

#banner-lil h3 {
    color: #d41515;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#newsletter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b14.png") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #041e42;
    background-position: 20% 30%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#newsletter h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

#newsletter p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #818ea0;
}

#newsletter span {
    color: #f38c05;
}

#newsletter .form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 40%;
}

#newsletter input {
    height: 3.125em;
    padding: 0 1.25em;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

#newsletter button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color:#088178;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 20px ;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}  

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer .logo {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

footer h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

footer a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer .follow {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

footer .follow i {
    color: #3b5998;    
    padding-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(2) {
    color: #00acee;
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(3) {
    color: #8a3ab9;
    #E60023
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(4) {
    color:  #E60023;
}

footer .install .row img {
    border: 1px solid #088178;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer .install img {
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
}

footer a:hover{
    color: #088178;
}

footer .copyright {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Shop Page*/


/*Single Product*/


/*Blog Page*/


/*About Page*/


/*Cart Page*/


/*Start Media Query*/

@media (max-width:799px) {
    #navbar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -300px;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #E3E6F3;
        box-shadow: 0 40px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        padding: 80px 0 0 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    #navbar.active {
        right: 0px;
   }

    #navbar li {
        margin-bottom: 25px
    }
    #mobile {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #mobile i {
       color: #1a1a1a;
       font-size: 24px;
       padding: 20px;
    }
    #close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8848882185.js"></script>
<section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="C:\Website Projects\Second Project=E-Commerce\Web images\logotxt.png" class="logo" alt="E-commerce logo"></a>
    <div>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="account.html">Log In</a></li>   
            <a href="#" id="close"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>            
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="mobile">
        <a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
        <i id="bar "class="fa-solid fa-bars active"></i></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have so little mistake that you unable to see it. be careful next time.your a tag in doesn't have an opener and also has space in your `id`

```
<i id="bar "class="fa-solid fa-bars active"></i></a>
```

thus your

```
const bar = document.getElementById("bar");
```

is `null`

change it to

```
 <a><i id="bar"class="fa-solid fa-bars active"></i></a>
```

everything else looks fine.

```js
const bar = document.getElementById("bar");
const nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

if (bar) {
  bar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("bar click event");
    nav.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}

if (close) {
  close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600; 700; 800; 900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif; 
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #222;
}

h2{
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #222;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #222;
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.section-p1 {
    padding: 40px 80px;
}

.section-m1 {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
}

/*Header Start*/

#header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background: #E3E6F3;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
    color: #088178;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
    content: "";
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 20px;
}

#mobile {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Home Page*/

#hero{
    background-image: url("Web images/img/hero4.png");
    height: 99vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top 25% right 0;
    padding: 0 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#hero h4{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#hero h1{
    color: #088178;
}

#hero button {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/button.png");
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #088178;
    border: 0;
    padding: 14px 80px 14px 65px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#hero button:hover {
    color: #46bff7;
}

#Feature {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#Feature .fe-box {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

#Feature .fe-box:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 54px rgba(70, 62, 221, 0.1);
}

#Feature .fe-box img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Feature .fe-box h6 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 8px 6px 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #088178;
    background-color: #fddde4;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(2) h6 {
    background-color: #cdebbc;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(3) h6{
    background-color: #d1e8f2;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(4) h6 {
    background-color: #cdd4f8;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(5) h6 {
    background-color: #f6dbf6;
}

#Feature .fe-box:nth-child(6) h6{
    background-color: #fff2e5;
}

#product1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#product1 .pro {
    width: 23%;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin: 15px 0;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;
}

#product1 .pro:hover {
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

#product1 .pro img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro .des {
    text-align: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#product1 .pro .des span {
    color: #606063;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#product1 .pro .des h5 {
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 13.7px;
}

#product1 .pro .des i  {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(241, 186, 7);
}

#product1 .pro .des h4 {
    padding-top: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #088178;
}

#product1 .pro .cart {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #cce7d0;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #088178;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
}

#banner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b2.jpg") ;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
}

#banner h4 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#banner h2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#banner h2 span{
    color: red;
}

#banner button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px 20px ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#banner button:hover {
    background: #088178;
    color: #fff;
}

#sm-banner{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
} 

#sm-banner .banner-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b17.jpg");
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 48%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sm-banner .BB2 {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b10.jpg");
}

#sm-banner .banner-box h4 {
    color: #fff;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 33px;
}
#sm-banner .banner-box span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box .cont {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box button {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 26px ;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#sm-banner .banner-box:hover button {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #088178;
    background-color: #088178;
}

#banner-lil {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 80px;
} 

#banner-lil .banner-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b18.jpg");
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-height: 30%;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 30%;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#banner-lil .BB3 {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b4.jpg");
}

#banner-lil .BB4  {
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b7.jpg");
}

#banner-lil .BB4 h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}

#banner-lil h4 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

#banner-lil h3 {
    color: #d41515;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#newsletter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image: url("Web images/img/banner/b14.png") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #041e42;
    background-position: 20% 30%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#newsletter h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

#newsletter p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #818ea0;
}

#newsletter span {
    color: #f38c05;
}

#newsletter .form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 40%;
}

#newsletter input {
    height: 3.125em;
    padding: 0 1.25em;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

#newsletter button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color:#088178;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 20px ;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}  

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer .logo {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

footer h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

footer a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer .follow {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

footer .follow i {
    color: #3b5998;    
    padding-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(2) {
    color: #00acee;
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(3) {
    color: #8a3ab9;
}

footer .follow i:nth-child(4) {
    color:  #E60023;
}

footer .install .row img {
    border: 1px solid #088178;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer .install img {
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
}

footer a:hover{
    color: #088178;
}

footer .copyright {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Shop Page*/


/*Single Product*/


/*Blog Page*/


/*About Page*/


/*Cart Page*/


/*Start Media Query*/

@media (max-width:799px) {
    #navbar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -300px;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #E3E6F3;
        box-shadow: 0 40px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        padding: 80px 0 0 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    #navbar.active {
        right: 0px;
   }

    #navbar li {
        margin-bottom: 25px
    }
    #mobile {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #mobile i {
       color: #1a1a1a;
       font-size: 24px;
       padding: 20px;
    }
    #close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8848882185.js"></script>
<section id="header">
  <a href="#"
    ><img
      src="C:\Website Projects\Second Project=E-Commerce\Web images\logotxt.png"
      class="logo"
      alt="E-commerce logo"
  /></a>
  <div>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="account.html">Log In</a></li>
      <a href="#" id="close"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mobile">
    <a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
    <i id="bar" class="fa-solid fa-bars active"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to solve the problem through your answer